# Not able to connect to BOE RAS 4.0 Error- enterpriseLogonFailed at ReportSDKEnterpriseLogonException

Tags: java, business-objects

when we are trying to run the report from Application getting below error:

> Error code:-2147217397 Error code name:enterpriseLogonFailed at
> com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKEnterpriseLogonException.throwReportSDKEnterpriseLogonException

Not able to connect to the BOE RAS 4.0 server from my local machine.
I have googled and did following:

- Able to ping the machine (remote location).
- Using administrator credentials to login.
- Checked the credentials and able to login in CMC.
- Debugged the code and found:

  ```
  ReportDocument clientDoc = new ReportDocument();
  clientDoc.open("rassdk://" + reportName, OpenReportOptions._retrieveNoReportDefinition);
  ```

  It's the `open()` method which is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

After all debugging, we found the guest user in BOE is disable.
After enabling it, it works. now it's login with the guest user.

Thank you much for all you input.
Hitesh